# Cocos2d - Passing a CCSprite to a child layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene, a main layer and a child layer, the main layer contains a Player* object which is a subclass of CCSprite, I want to pass the Player into the child layer like so:

```
BattleLayer* b = [[BattleLayer alloc] initWithPlayer:_player];
[((CCScene*)self.parent) addChild:b];

-(id)initWithPlayer:(Player *)p
{
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
        _player = p;
        [self addChild:_player.spriteSheet];
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, this gives an error when I do [self addChild:_player.spriteSheet];

```
*** Assertion failure in -[BattleLayer addChild:z:tag:]
```

I've tried removing the sprite from the main layer before passing it in, but even with cleanup:NO this gives an error of

```
*** -[CCSpriteBatchNode tag]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x747a580
```

What am I doing wrong here? And what's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run in to this before and retained and then released after reordering.  My objects were autoreleased and retained only by the CCLayer so this worked, Try:

```
[_player retain];
[_player removeFromParentAndCleanUp:YES];
[self addChild:_player];
[_player release];
```

However I have run into a bug with rapid removal and re-adding of sprites and it is described here:  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9980

Answer (score 2):

I can see one of three things causing an addSprite assertion failure.

- p is nil
- p.spriteSheet is nil
- or finally, p.spriteSheet already has a parent (ie spriteSheet has already been added to a CCNode beforehand)

Comment: So what do I do if p.Spritesheet has a parent? [_player.spriteSheet removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; isn't helping